# Unable to access windows share using samba

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I am trying to mount Windows share on local network but I fail every time. It gives me this message when I try and load it.

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I did some searching on internet and one post suggested to check if share exist. I run this command.

```
smbclient -L //192.168.11.3/media -U media
```

And this is what I get.

```
OS=[Windows 7 Ultimate 7601 Service Pack 1] Server=[Windows 7 Ultimate 6.1]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    // all folders are appearing in this list.

Connection to 192.168.11.3 failed (Error NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND)
NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Please suggest something so I can mount this share. I'm on Xenial.

Comment: If the Windows 7 is in a domain member, you may have to use the computer name instead the ip address.

Comment: It is but we always have connected to this share via samba but I have come to Linux after few months and now this happened.